How to set context on firebase messaging.onBackgroundMessage?
On our website we are using push notifications using firebase. To receive notifications when the website is not the active tab we are using a service worker which looks like this:
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

const firebaseConfig = {......};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
let angularClient;

addEventListener('message', event => {
  // if message is a "ping" string, 
  // we store the client-website which sent the message into angularClient variable
  if (event.data == "ping") {
    angularClient = event.source;
  }
});

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    '[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ',
    payload
  );

  //angularClient is undefined!?
  angularClient.postMessage({ title: payload.data.title, text: payload.data.text });

  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.text,
    icon: '/assets/icons/512.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

First when the website loads it registers the worker. When that is done it sends a "ping" to the worker which is handled in addEventListener('message', ...).
The worker then stores the source of the message as the angularClient.
Then when a message from firebase is received while the website is in the background messaging.onBackgroundMessage is executed. There I want the website to know that a message was received and do something with it. However the angularClient is undefined there. I believe this has something to do with different contexts.
So how do I make it so that angularClient is defined in messaging.onBackgroundMessage?
I already tried using call(). But then the registration for the onBackgroundMessage fails.
